# Is it possible to add hibernate validator settings via configuration properties in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

At the moment, I'm doing it via `META-INF/validation.xml` file:

```
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration" version="1.1">
    <property name="hibernate.validator.allow_parameter_constraint_override">true</property>
    <!--other properties-->
</validation-config>
```

Does Spring Boot provide any possibility to do the same (to set those `hibernate.validator` settings) via configuration properties (in `application.properties`/`application.yml`)?

If no, is there any other way to get rid of `validation.xml` file (e.g. with overriding some beans etc.)?

Comment: this url will help you -> https://bushansirgur.in/spring-boot-validation-using-hibernate-validator/

Comment: @vaibhavsahu no, it won't. The link doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the validator beans and configure them like this:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = 
    Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )   
        .configure()
        .customViolationExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel(ExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel.BEAN_METHODS)
        .buildValidatorFactory();
```

or

```
Configuration<?> config = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
((ConfigurationImpl)config).constraintExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel(
    ExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel.BEAN_METHODS);

ValidatorFactory factory = config.buildValidatorFactory();
```

etc. (courtesy of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#el-features ), but TBH I wouldn't call that a "better" way than just providing the XML with the config itself, unless you need to set it up based on some run-time factors.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring Boot 3.0 you can now declare a `ValidationConfigurationCustomizer` instance, which is allowed to add properties, or if cast as provider-specific implementations can use type-safe declarations instead:

As a functional bean definition with a text property change:

```
@Bean
public ValidationConfigurationCustomizer allowParameterConstraintOverride() {
    return (configuration) -> configuration.addProperty(
        HibernateValidatorConfiguration.ALLOW_PARAMETER_CONSTRAINT_OVERRIDE, "true");
}
```

or as a type-safe functional bean definition:

```
    @Bean
    public ValidationConfigurationCustomizer allowParameterConstraintOverride2() {
        return (config) -> {
            if (config instanceof HibernateValidatorConfiguration hvConfig) {
                hvConfig.allowOverridingMethodAlterParameterConstraint(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

or you could declare a re-usable class and `@Import` it in the various applications you want to apply it to:

```
public class AllowParameterConstraintOverride implements ValidationConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Configuration<?> config) {
        if (config instanceof HibernateValidatorConfiguration hvConfig) {
            hvConfig.allowOverridingMethodAlterParameterConstraint(true);
        }
    }
}

@Import(AllowParameterConstraintOverride)
class MyConfiguration {
}
```